# Can't upload profile image on small screen sizes / smartphone

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, image-upload

I try to Change my Profile Image on Stack Overflow but I can't Upload the Image with Opera Browser in my Smartphone. The loaded layer when I push Upload New Image is Not responsive.

I can't resize the side to hit the save Button. The save button is hidden.
How can this be fixed?

[image: Responsive bug]

Comment: SE can't support any possible browser. Use a more standard browser like Chrome and it should work fine. [Here is the full list of supported browsers](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/). Good luck! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron This is a responsivity issue, not a browser-specific one. It looks the same in [Chrome on a mobile-sized screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNaF5.png).

Comment: Yup. Same on iOS Safari. It's not stacks-compliant yet. I can get to the upload button if I turn my phone to landscape mode (half of the button is visible) but that's not a super awesome solution. :)

Comment: Possibly related (from a few days ago): *[Stack Exchange stopped working in some browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376749/)* and *[Can you please fix the show-stopping post bug already?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376845/)*

Comment: @Larnu A bit late, but just for the record this question was initially asked over at Main where it gathered one downvote (which is what I guess the OP meant with *up*vote...) before it was migrated here and votes reset (but not comments...)

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this wasn't browser related - just viewport width related on an older component with fixed widths and mins.

Adjusted to set max width to 100% and cleaned up a couple downstream styles.  Should work reasonably well, although we'll probably want to do more cleanup in the future on this component to make it fully responsive.

[image: Screenshot of image uploader at various viewport widths]